# Call a Custom Dialog with a Map Inside FROM a RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

Im having a problem here.

I have a RecyclerView with some Tasks to do. I have an adapter for it where I add the items according of what I need.

What I want is to call a Dialog when I do a LongClick on an Item. This Dialog has more Info about the task Im gonna select, and also it has a Map on it.

I dont have problems calling the othe dialog and putting the text on there. The problem is with the Map. The first time I call it, works fine. The second time it gives me this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
```

So, maybe the problem is that Im not calling the SupportMapFragment and that. My problem is, how do I start the map every time I click one item? Since the adapter does not extend any fragment or anything.